# VBA .VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString isn't working

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a bunch of workbooks dynamically that are linked and I need to suppress the linked warning, so I am trying to add a `Workbook_Open()` sub with the proper code.

Only problem is that the code isn't actually being added to the workbook.

```
' do not display alerts while processing so many files
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbNew.SaveAs FileName:=path, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False

' add a little Workbook_Open method to the new workbook's ThisWorkbook dynamically
' this line doesn't actually do anything - why?
wbNew.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString ( _
    "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" & vbCrLf _
    & "    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False" & vbCrLf _
    & "    Application.DisplayAlerts = False" & vbCrLf _
    & "End Sub")
wbNew.Save  
wbNew.Close
```

The file is created and all is well, except that no code is actually added to the workbook I just made, it's a normal workbook and its ThisWorkbook is blank. (I also checked that I wasn't suppressing any warnings about the dynamic code writing, just the normal saveas prompts).

How can I make this work?

Comment: You're not saving the workbook as a macro-enabled format...  You probably want `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`  (52)  "Open XML Workbook Macro Enabled"

Comment: @Comintern if VBProject permission is not already granted, this will raise an error.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I've had the option checked so long I forgot what happened when it wasn't set. I think @ TimWilliams hit the nail on the head.

Comment: This works as expected up until the `.Close` method If you comment out that line and leave the `wbNew` open, you can confirm this. Tim's comment is spot on.

Comment: Your use of `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is suppressing the dialog that warns you your XLSX file format does not permit macros.

Comment: @TimWilliams was correct. Unfortunately I still couldn't get rid of the warning with this code and I now get an additional prompt to allow for macro-enabled content.

Comment: @rib.usa...Dumb question but do you have the extensibility reference checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, no prompts or missing codes:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wbnew As Workbook

    Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbnew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\abc.xlsm", FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    wbnew.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.AddFromString ( _
        "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" & vbCrLf _
        & "    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False" & vbCrLf _
        & "    Application.DisplayAlerts = False" & vbCrLf _
        & "End Sub")

    wbnew.Close True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

For macro prompt settting Fil--> Options--> Trust Center --> Macro Setting to this will get rid of the prompt:
[image]